# How to access dataframe column in pyspark and do string comparision?

Tags: pyspark

I have a python function which return True/False depends on value of a data frame column.

```
def check_name(df):
  if ((df.name == "ABC")):
      return ((df.Value < 0.80))

    return (df.Value == 0)
```

And I pass this function into my query as `myFunction`:

```
def myQuery(myFunction):
    df.filter(...).groupBy(...).withColumn('Result', when(myFunction(df), 0).otherwise(1))
```

But it fails

```
Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.
```

I think the problem is this `df.name == "ABC"`

I have tried changing to `F.col('name')` == "ABC", but I get the same error.

Can you please tell me how to fix my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if-else code should be instructions (`when.otherwise`) in spark.

```
def check_name(df):
    return F.when(df.id == "ABC", df.score1 < 0.80).otherwise(df.score1 == 0)
```

and then if `myFunction` must return `boolean` and you are inverting the boolean value (`true = 0, false = 1`), you can simplify the `myQuery` to be

```
def myQuery(myFunction):
    return (df.filter(...)
            .groupBy(...)
            .withColumn('Result', (~myFunction(df).cast('int')))
```

Comment: Thanks Emma.  Is it possible for me to reference a python array like
``` def check_name(df, anArg): 
           condition_array = call_function_to_get_an_array(anArg)
          return F.when(df.id in condition_array ,  df.score1 < 0.80).otherwise(df.score1 == 0) ```

Comment: That is a separate question, please open as the new question and explain how you are building the array in the function.